# Can I 'style' and use a label as a 'normal' element

Tags: html, css

I have discover a way to have an input and label elements as an accordion viewer.

To center vertically my elements I use the label as if it was a div, that is, giving it `display:table` and create a div inside it.
So I have :

```html
<div>
    <input id='myid'>
    <label for ='myid' style='display table'>
        <div style='display:table-cell'>
            <img ....... > 
            thetextforthelabel 
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Ok, this works fine.

My question is: am I doing something 'forbiden' ? 
Can I use the label tag as a container ?

I know that it can be not orthodox .. but It works for me...

Comment: what's your actual purpose? what visual result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it's invalid to have a block level element ('div') inside a inline element ('label'), but if you dont mind about the html being valid then its not a major concern

Comment: @atmd Be careful with claims like that - in some cases the browser will reject it so hard it will break things. Try `<p><div>red?</div></p>` with CSS `p>div {color:red}` and see what happens!

Comment: @atmd , not strictly true. HTML5 allows <a> tags to wrap <div>s, for example?

Comment: To Fabricio : I have discover a goob behaviour to center vertically things using table & table-cell. To atmd : why is it invalid and who would invalid my html ? Could I have problems with forms data use ?

Comment: To me it seems like you've answered the question yourself. You're not doing something totally forbidden, but it works. It's not something that you should really do though. To answer your question though, it is accessible to be styled just as any other element.

Comment: @iamdash thats right, using a html5 doctype will allow it. @ Niet the Dark Absol, I agree with what you are saying that sometimes the css will be ignored, I took the question to be 'i've styled this, but should i' rather then 'is this possible' I'd assume if the OP's css wasnt working then the question would be different

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid.

The problem is that [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) elements can only be used

> Where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected.

However, the [content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model) of [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) elements is

> [Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), but with no descendant [labelable elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label)
>   unless it is the element's [labeled control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#labeled-control), and no descendant
>   [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) elements.

Anyways, it will probably work, because (unlike e.g. [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements) the end tag of `label` elements can't be omitted:

> Neither tag is omissable

However, I'm not sure of the advantage of having a table element with a single cell. Consider using the following instead:

```
<div>
    <input id='myid'>
    <label for='myid' style='display:block'>
        <img ....... > 
        thetextforthelabel 
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using this to center vertically things.  My doubt is : Could this fail in the future ?

Comment: @civiltomain Probably not. But what exactly are you centering? If the table had multiple cells, you could vertically center the content of each cell, relatively to the table. But your table has a single cell.

Comment: If you have a div with 100px and display:table , and have an inner div with 20px height (or the height needed) and display:table-cell, vertical-align:middle and this last is automatically vertically center !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is forbidden by the formal rules of HTML. And yes, it works, and the parsing rules of HTML mean that it must work. So this is different from, say, the rule that says that a `p` element must not contain a `div` element; *that* rule is enforced by the parsing process (the `p` element is implicitly closed when `<div>` is encountered).

On the other hand, if the content is just an image and text, you don’t need a `div` element but can use `span`. In rendering, it does not matter (with the usual CSS caveats) which one you select, since their only difference in rendering is with the default `display` value, and you are assigning a `display` value anyway.

```html
<div>
    <input id='myid'>
    <label for ='myid' style='display table'>
        <span style='display:table-cell'>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" alt="(an image)">
            thetextforthelabel 
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```